# Can an Envoy Sidecar use an HTTP/HTTPS proxy for egress traffic

Tags: envoyproxy

We have a service and an Envoy sidecar deployed in a K8S pod. All ingress and egress traffic goes through Envoy which works great. However our production environment is locked down and all HTTP/HTTPS traffic must go through a Proxy provided via the standard `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variables.

Envoy is routing requests using the `http_connection_manager` filter, referencing targets defined in `clusters`.

*Is there a way to get Envoy to use the proxy server for its egress http traffic*? Either using the `https_proxy` environment variable or defining the egress https proxy some other way.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a cluster for the proxy based on the domain name of the proxy:

```
- name: example_proxy
  connect_timeout: 5s
  type: LOGICAL_DNS
  hosts: [{ socket_address: { address: proxy.example.com, port_value: 80 }}]
```

or the IP address of the proxy:

```
- name: example_proxy_ipv4
  connect_timeout: 5s
  type: STATIC
  hosts: [{ socket_address: { address: 192.0.2.1, port_value: 80 }}]
```

Then use `http_connection_manager` filters to route all traffic not matching the other rules to this cluster.